# get selected file path in windows explorer with Java

Tags: java, image, background, path, explorer

I'm developping a Java application in which the user is able to change the background of a JFrame using a picture from his computer.

In order to do that I'm trying to get the path name of the picture he selects in windows explorer.

I use this code to open the explorer but I can't figure out what I got to do next to get the selected file path...

```
p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select,C:\\directory\\selectedFile").start();
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Works great with JFileChooser. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) instead.

Then retrieve the selected file as a `File` object using the [getSelectedFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29) method.

Answer (score -1):

Better option is [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for selecting a file.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Answer (score -2):

That *may* be possible, but it is much easier to use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).  You can set the look and feel to mimic the current environment (Windows, in your case).  I recommend googling JFileChooser as there are tons of examples (including in the API).